# Excel - VBA to automatically expand autofilter if new/moved column is outside range

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I work with large(ish) data sets in excel and am constantly moving and/or adding columns to my data. Every now and then I move or add a column to the first/last column position and FORGET to reset the auto filter. These moved or new columns are not automatically added to the filter and if I sort at any point before realising my error, my data is shot.

I was wondering if there is a way to either 1) force excel to automatically update the filter range to always include new/moved columns even if they fall outside the range or 2) force excel to throw up a simple message to say something like "Careful, you have columns outside the filter range".

I know this problem is based in user-error but I am surprised there is not already a warning message of this kind, and also surprised that I cannot find Google search evidence of anyone else having the same problem (come on, I can't be the only one).

I have searched everywhere, but cannot find anything. I have not written any Worksheet_Change macros yet, but am fairly proficient in vba.

Hope someone can help...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track to use `Worksheet_Change`.  Here's a starter that uses the `Workbook_SheetChange` event so every sheet in the workbook is tested.  It updates the Autofilter if a column adjacent to the current Autofilter area is modified (inserted or edited)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Sh
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        With ws.AutoFilter.Range
            If (Target.Column < .Column) And (Target.Column + Target.Columns.Count >= .Column - Target.Columns.Count) Or _
               (Target.Column >= .Column + .Columns.Count) Then
                Set rng = ws.AutoFilter.Range
                ws.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
                ws.Range(Target, rng).AutoFilter
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```